# Joomla 3.0 and modules.php: static variable(2d) and caching - output error

Tags: joomla, static-variables, joomla3.0

I have the following problem:

I use Joomla 3.0.1 and my own developed Template(with bootstrap). When I turn the normal Joomla caching  to on, my site has output errors. These errors are regarding to the `modules.php` from my template, because I use a static variable(array) to save all loaded module positions and the calulated or preseted spans for `bootstrap` in an 2 dimensional array. Like this:

```
top ->2,4,6
left ->3,3,3,3
right ->4,4,4
bottom ->1,2,3,4,2
header ->12
footer ->6,6
```

Without caching it works perfect, but when i turn it on, i have following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: logo in
>      /root/templates/jooag_workframe30/html/modules.php on line 82 
>   Notice: Undefined index: mainmenu in
>      /root/templates/jooag_workframe30/html/modules.php on line 72

I know what this means and where to look, but i have no solution to fix this.

**The modules.php code is here:**

http://pastebin.com/s4tjXcKR

**The entire template is here:**

http://www.mediafire.com/?qrkbatdcbs4iq2v

Comment: You'll have a better chance getting an answer if you include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a position doesn't contain any modules (ie $modCount = 0) the $spanMatrix array won't have its key, so you should be checking whether it exists before trying to access it

I suggest you wrap lines 72-75 AND line 82 of your `modules.php` in the following statement:

```
if( isset( $spanMatrix[$modPosition] ))
{
.....
}
```

Let me know if it works